# DryIoC migrating from Autofac: Resolve with ResolveParameter not possible

Tags: c#, dryioc

I am trying to resolve TestClassC, with a specified fake instance of ITestInterface. Doing this with Autofac was possible by specifying a ResolveParameter. Is this possbile with DryIoC at all? I have read through the documentation and some other threads on here with similiar problems and did not find a way to specify things in Resolve. My requirement is to pass this test.

```
    private class TestClassB : ITestInterface { }

    private class TestClassC
    {
        public TestClassC(ITestInterface instance)
        {
            Instance = instance;
        }

        public ITestInterface Instance { get; }
    }        

    [TestCase("key")]
    public void RegisterKeyedDependency_WhenCalled_EqualsExpected(string key)
    {
        var Container = new Container();
        var fake = A.Fake<ITestInterface>();

        Container.Register<TestClassC>();
        Container.UseInstance(fake, serviceKey: key);
        Container.Register<ITestInterface, TestClassB>(Reuse.Singleton);

        var result1 = Container.Resolve<TestClassC>();
        var result2 = Container.Resolve<TestClassC>(/* How to specify that I want to use the fake here */);

        Assert.That(result1.Instance, Is.Not.EqualTo(fake));
        Assert.That(result2.Instance, Is.EqualTo(fake));
    }
```

Edit: I found a possible solution, which is unsatisfiying but will do for now.

```
    [Pure]
    public static T ResolveWithDependency<T, TDependency>(this Container container, string key)
    {
        return container.Resolve<Func<TDependency, T>>().Invoke(container.Resolve<TDependency>(key));
    }
```

Basically DryIoC will keep the dependency open if you Resolve it with a Func. However this gets very tedious if you have more than one dependency that you want to choose at Resolve time. If you would want it for like 5 dependencies, then you have to choose a Func with 5 parameters, it's not as nice as the Autofac ResoleParameter API.

Comment: I messed with this for about 20 minutes. Even when I drastically simplified what I was trying to do, it couldn't resolve some very simple keyed registrations. I'm sure the problem is behind my keyboard, but it was a struggle and the exception messages were not helpful.